# How to make each JanusGraph Server within its Kubernetes Cluster communicate with the co-located Cassandra Server in its Kubernetes Cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, solr, cassandra, janusgraph, k8ssandra

As far as I understand from the `JanusGraph docs`: https://docs.janusgraph.org/operations/deployment/ , and from this Google Group Talk: https://groups.google.com/g/janusgraph-users/c/ZOoR1vRLfvo?pli=1 , The *JanusGraph Servers* are *standalone independent servers* that do not communicate with each other, and the coordination is achieved through the underlying storage backend, which, as Cassandra, can be put into a Kubernetes Cluster.

But would it be convenient to set a Kubernetes Cluster for the JanusGraph standalone independent servers as well?
How to do it, and how to make each single standalone independent JanusGraph Server within its Kubernetes Cluster communicate with the co-located Cassandra Server in its Kubernetes Cluster?

[image]